# DDL Trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ddl-trigger

Are there any options for running DDL triggers in a MySQL database. I would like to create a view every time someone create a table.

If the "Users" table is created, I want the DDL trigger to create a view called "v_Users".

Comment: MySQL doesn't support them

Comment: Thx :) Then i will look for an alternative

Comment: I'm curious... What are you gaining by having the `VIEW`?

Comment: @Rick James: Security, does not want users to have access directly to tables. Then I can build an additional security layer.

Comment: @sv88erik - And yet you are willing to let users execute `CREATE TABLE`??

Comment: @Rick James: only database admin or if user have a role with privileges to do that. dbo is the only one that can acsess table direct.

Comment: But this is off-topic. How the security model works is not included in the question :) But if you want to discuss it. Please feel free to contact me.

Comment: I updated this to show you exactly how to do this in PostgreSQL https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210343/2639

Comment: I don't understand this. If the users aren't allowed to create the tables, then only giving them select privileges on the tables would serve the same purpose, wouldn't it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, I have row permission in the views and table tiggers

Comment: How do you get those "row permissions" into the view?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I will create view based the source tabel with filter. I have do this for years in SQL Server

Comment: @sv88erik - perhaps a simple example would help us understand.

Comment: I think if you come from a SQL Server background you have to wrap your head around the fact that you're not using a real database anymore, and I'm not sure you're there. There are no MySQL DBAs, just people that excel at pseudo-castles atop sandy foundations.

Comment: Even if you get those "row permissions on the view" why not just put them on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL only supports triggers for `BEFORE` / `AFTER` `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, see documentation for the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) syntax.

An alternative solution might be to create a MySQL [`EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) that runs at at a specified interval and checks whether there are any tables that don't have corresponding views, and if so, create them. (Make sure to enable the event scheduler. The default is OFF until MySQL 8.0. See documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html).)

Maybe another option would be to create the view "if not exists" whenever a row of data is `INSERT`ed into the table, in which case you could use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. (One obvious disadvantage of this approach is that the trigger will be fired every time you `INSERT` to the table, so there is a performance penalty on `INSERT`.)

**Edit:** Maybe yet another option could be that you only allow `CREATE TABLE` through a special [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) which will automatically also create the view.

Comment: @sv88erik I've just added yet another option to my answer.

Comment: I do not really like the last solution. Likes that things are relational so that no matter how to create a table, it will always be a view for it

Answer (score 1):

> Thx :) Then i will look for an alternative

Because you will look for an alternative, let me suggest PostgreSQL. It does everything MySQL does, except better. Except lose your data, it tries not to do that at all. For comparison PostgreSQL supports exactly what you want with triggers on DDL using the "Event Trigger" functionality -- an extension of the spec

## Event Triggers

For more information see [PostgreSQL: Event Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html). Here is an example if what they look like,

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigf()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF (SELECT object_identity = 'public.users'
      FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands())
    THEN
      CREATE VIEW v_Users AS TABLE users;
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER foo ON ddl_command_end
  WHEN tag IN ( 'CREATE TABLE' )
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf();

CREATE TABLE users (bleh int DEFAULT 9);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (5), (DEFAULT);
INSERT 0 2
test=# SELECT * FROM v_users ;
 bleh 
-------
     5
     9
```

---

Microsoft SQL Server, a substantially more expensive closed-source & proprietary option with less functionality supports this with their [ddl-trigger's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: To complete the "alternatives": Oracle and Firebird 3.0 also support DDL triggers

Comment: Thank you very much for the option. But unfortunately, it's not my decision in the choice of technology. If I had chosen I had chosen SQL Sever. So what I put in alternative is another way to solve the problem.

Anyway +1! :)